# how to check if eles condition in alert in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my below code i have one field and one button and without fill the text filed then alert msg is show plz fill the input text .

right now in my code when i submit the button without input text filled then alert is not show .

How can we do that. anybody help me out this.

My full code https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-microservice-w8bfz

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Name <input type="text"  />
        
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

handleClick = (event) => {
  console.log('test')
  };
```

Comment: anyone help me out how can we do that??

Comment: You'll need to use state. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Hey @rennukumari, my answer is updated. There was a typo in it. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have state inorder to make the input field (name) controlled.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: "" };
  }

  handleClick = (event) => {
    if (!this.state.name) {
      alert("Name should not be empty !");
    }
  };
  changeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Name :
        <input
          id="name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          name="aname"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.changeHandler}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. You need to use a state variable for this.

**Explanation:**

> - I have defined state variable `name` and used that in textbox
> - On change of input value I am assigning input text inside `name` variable
> - And then on handleClick, checking whether it's empty or not and based on that showing `alert box`

**Working example:** [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-brattain-qi24y?file=/src/index.js)

### Solution

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
       name: '' 
    };
  }


  handleClick = () => {    
    if (!this.state.name) {
      alert('Please enter');
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Name{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```